# What is the maximum file size one can download using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I have started testing with small files, and now I'm wondering

> What is the maximum file size, I can download using `FtpWebRequest`?

I googled and found the [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=484451). But still I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow, any expert comments from stackoverflow ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit maximum.

It depends on the server and on the reliability of the connection.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, lot of other forums suggest to use WebClient and Asyn method.Ofcourse server and conn is most important too but still am worrying about my code part.

Comment: @Usher: `WebClient` uses `FtpWebRequest` under the covers; I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: let me test with my my existing code ,i have video file size is 480Meg.i will post the result once its done. Thanks again SLaks

Comment: ,sorry for the delayed result,i couldn't find the test server to install FTP and test.Finally took so long to find one. Tested 2.26GB file takes 2.57 mins to download.Thanks all for your help